# What's the difference between mongo's update $set and upsert: true

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I wanted to ask this question and answer it because I was going through the mongo documentation for updateMany() and UpdateOne(), and as a beginner, I was initially confused about the difference between using the $set operator and the "upsert: true" option.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the documentation says:

Mongo Update: [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.

Mongo Update: [$upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-upsert-behavior)

> If document(s) match the query criteria, db.collection.update()performs an update.

> If no document matches the query criteria, db.collection.update() inserts a single document.

**ANSWER**: Essentially the difference is that the $set operator will create a new **field** if the update query finds the document but not the field specified. If the update query doesn't find the document, the update function is acknowledged but nothing is updated or created.

The option <upsert: true> will create a new **document** if the query doesn't find the the document specified.

Both $set and upsert will perform an update if the query results in a match.